# How to convert greyscale bmp in imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick, bmp

I am trying to convert a greyscale png to a bitmap (bmp3 version) with the following attributes:

`Format: BMP3 (Microsoft Windows bitmap image (V3))
  Class: PseudoClass
  Type: Grayscale
  Endianess: Undefined
  Colorspace: Gray
  Depth: 8-bit
  Channel depth:
    gray: 2-bit`

The problem is that I need the specific configuration above (taken by identify -verbose test.bmp) made from GIMP otherwise the one I get from imagemagick

`Format: BMP3 (Microsoft Windows bitmap image (V3))
  Class: PseudoClass
  Type: Bilevel
  Endianess: Undefined
  Colorspace: Gray
  Depth: 1-bit
  Channel depth:
    gray: 1-bit`

makes the white into black. This image is being sent to a thermal printer.

I've used the following:

`convert test_tcl.png -colors 16 +dither -type bilevel BMP3:test.bmp`

Using file, I've seen that the images that can be correctly printed from the device should be in the following format:

`$ file test_gimp3.bmp
test.bmp: PC bitmap, Windows 3.x format, 192 x 192 x 8`

whereas, mine are:

`$ file test.bmp
test.bmp: PC bitmap, Windows 3.x format, 192 x 192 x 1`

How can I produce the output from above (8bit/2bit)?

Answer (score 2):

So my issue was with the palette.

when I used:

`$ convert test.png -type Optimize -compress none BMP3:test.bmp`

I got the output I needed.